# Math notation for function broadcasting

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, notation

Say $\delta(x):\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is some real valued function. In computer science, many languages provide function broadcasting, defined as the application of a function to each element of a vector. For example, in the Julia programming language, this is given by the dot operator. For example, $\delta.(\vec{x})= \begin{bmatrix} \delta(x_1) & \delta(x_2) & ... & \delta(x_n) \end{bmatrix}^\top$.

I wanted to know what is the math notation for broadcasting a function in a matrix (particularly one-dimensional matrices, vectors). So far, whenever dealing with this, I simply try to find a vectorial notation for whatever my function does and define an alternative, suitable vector-valued function. For example, assume $\delta(x)=\frac{x}{c}, c \in \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$. Then I define what in Julia would be `δ.(x)` for a vector `x` as

$$\vec{\delta}(\vec{x}):=\frac{1}{c}\times \vec{x} $$

This function performrs the scalar product of $1/c$ with $\vec{x}$ and its result is equivalent to broadcasting $\delta$ across each element of $\vec{x}$. However, more complicated functions do not allow for such straightforward translations from real to vector spaces.

Comment: I don't think that there is a standard notation for such a thing.

Comment: If the vector or matrix is itself regarded as a function (from the set of indices to the set of possible entries), then broadcasting is simply composition of functions. But this is not a comfortable usage in everyday mathematics; a writer would need to define or explain it before using it. Also, it only applies to functions that have been named.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to define a broadcasting operator $f_{\large\ldotp}$ for a function $f$ defined by
$$f_{\large\ldotp}(A) = \{f(x)\mid x\in A\}$$
You can replace $A$ with a vector or a matrix. The advantage of this notation is that you get the preimage
$$f_{\large\ldotp}^{-1}(B) = \{x\mid f(x)\in B\}$$
without introducing any new notation.